# Using WFS-T in OpenLayers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wfs-t

How can I use WFS-T in openlayers-2?

I'm using [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/) in server side.

Comment: Read for example http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.8/examples/wfs-t.html and http://boundlessgeo.com/2014/06/openlayers-editing-wfs-t/. OpenGeo Suite comes with GeoEditor which is WFS-T client using OpenLayers.

Comment: What do you want to do with WFS? Do you want to just display the data? or do you want to edit the data using the Transactional editing with WFS?

Comment: i want to using Transaction Editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a save strategy as follow and add it to you map:

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();
```

Modify the features and then call:

```
saveStratefy.save();
```